# Using custom property value to set a color in a template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am not able to figure out, why this is not working:

I a have two buttons:

```
<Button Content="qwerty" BorderBrush="Tomato">
<Button Content="dvorak">
```

I adjust the looks of those buttons with this style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkRed" />
        <Setter Property="Template">         

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">                    
                    <Border x:Name="RootElement" CornerRadius="4">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBrush" Color="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                        </Border.Background>
 ...
```

The first button should have the color in the `x:Name="BorderBrush"` set to "Tomato" because i specified it in the button definition.

The second button has no `BorderBrush="..."` specified and therefore the default color `DarkRed` from `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkRed" />` should be used.

But it doesn't use any color at all.

If i hardcode the color like this `<SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBrush" Color="DarkRed" />`, then it works, but that is no good, since i need to be able to set the color in the button definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BorderBrush` is property is holding a `Brush` object but you try to bind it to a `Color` property of a `SolidColorBrush` which cannot work.

You need to use the `TemplateBinding` on the `Background` property of your border:

```
<Border x:Name="RootElement" CornerRadius="4" 
       Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
```

As an alternative solution you can bind the `Color` property of the parent's `BorderBrush` with the help of using the `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`:

```
<Border.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBrush" 
      Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                      Path=BorderBrush.Color}" />
</Border.Background>
```